# Cannot add owner info to Lock screen - HTC One M9

Tags: lock-screens, 6.0-marshmallow, htc, htc-one

In my other Android devices, I've always been able to set an "If found" message on the Owner Information shown on the lock screen.

`Settings -> Security -> Owner info`

But for the HTC One M9, this configuration item does not exist. I have not been able to find an alternate setting.

**Apart from writing the owner info on the lock screen image, is there any other way to display a message on the lock screen?**

Comment: Do you have a search option in your Settings app?

Comment: Yes, looking for 'Owner' finds nothing

Comment: Can you try this: http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/543755-owner-info-android-5-0-2-a.html (Last 2 posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android 7.0 `Nougat` release has added the lock screen message functionality.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a direct option. You could probably create your own lock screen wallpaper with your "if found" message on it.

Comment: *"Apart from writing the owner info on the lock screen image, is there any other way to display a message on the lock screen?"*